# Use certain modules on Ruby without installing them

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Let's take a simple example... there is a module out there that permits Ruby to read XML files. Cool.

Now, that module requires gem installation and stuff...

But I don't want that.

Can't I just get raw code and put it in my Ruby application? I tried looking, but no raw code could be found...

Now you will be wondering why the heck would I not want to install the gem. Well, I just want to know.. thanks.

Comment: Many languages have mechanisms built in making it easy to include separate source modules. Ruby supports several commands related to this, with `require` being the most used. Gems were designed to make it easy to work with that mechanism, while keeping them bundled and manageable in a way that allows convenient updating for bug-fixes and feature enhancements. You can ignore those conveniences but you're going against a strong flow, making a huge amount of work for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The module *is* the raw code, and downloading/installing the module does exactly what you want. Gem is the easiest way to download modules, but not the only option.

If you really want to, you can download the module (via gem or another method) and then manually copy its contents into your document. But, don't do it, it's not worth it - it's much easier to just leave the code in the file its in, and reference it.

Comment: http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/ that lets me read XML files. I download the .zip file, unzip, and now, what is the raw code supposed to be?

Comment: ReXML is part of Ruby. Why not simply `include 'rexml'` and let Ruby work as it's designed to work?

Comment: I'm using a Ruby version without it. There are motives I cannot update my Ruby version right now. And ReXML was mainly an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include it in your project to make it self contained, and not dependent on Rubygems, you could download the module and place it in the same folder as your project. You could download the module with Rubygems and make a copy, or you could download the module from it's project page / SCM.